# It rained for/over two hours

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, present-simple

What's the difference between 'for' 'over' and 'within' in these two different situations?

> 1A. The Central Bank plans to reduce the key rate **for** 2 years.
> 2A. The Central Bank plans to reduce the key rate **over** 2 years.
> 3A. The Central Bank plans to reduce the key rate **within** 2 years.

> 1B. It rained **for** 2 hours.
> 2B. It rained **over** 2 hours.
> 3B. It rained **within** 2 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1A - The rate will be lower for two years (but may increase at the end of that time)

2A - The rate will be gradually reduced over a period of two years.

3A- The rate will be lower after two years, possibly sooner.

1B - The rain lasted for two hours.

3B - It started to rain before two hours had passed.

2B isn't idiomatic, though we can say *It rained for over two hours* (the rain lasted longer than that).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It appears that in the first sentence (with the key rate) 'over' means the same as 'for' in the second sentence (with rain). Just because 'for' took another meaning, we have to use 'over' to express the usual meaning of 'for' (It'll rain for two hours). Do you agree with me here?

Comment: I understand _reduction for [time period]_ to mean that the lower rate will last that long, _reduction over [time period]_ that the rate will be gradually reduced during that time. In _It rained for over two hours_, 'over' means 'more than'.

Comment: I mean in this example (It rained for 2 hours) 'for' shows the duration of the action ***itself,*** while in this example(They reduced the key rate for two years) 'for' shows the duration of the result of the action: the lower rate lasted that long, and if we want to show the duration of the action itself as in the example with rain, we have to change 'for' to 'over' (They reduced the key rate over two years). I hope I managed to explain myself :) What do you think about this? :)

Comment: Isn't that what I said in my answer?

Comment: Maybe. I just wanted to hear whether you agree with that idea > *(It appears that in the first sentence (with the key rate) 'over' means the same as 'for' in the second sentence (with rain). Just because 'for' took another meaning, we have to use 'over' to express the usual meaning of 'for').* <

Comment: The difference is that  reducing an interest rate can be a gradual process or a sudden one, so we need different words to indicate which one we mean. This doesn't apply to whether it's raining or not. I wouldn't say that _for_ has different meanings.

Comment: 1). "for" in the example with key rate shows the duration of the result (in Russian we translate it as ***"на"),*** 2). "for" in the example with rain shows the duration of the action itself (we translate it as ***"в течение").***   3). "over" in the example with key rate shows the duration of the action itself (we translate it as "в течение" ***as in the 2.)*** Now, I hope I managed to explain myself

Comment: As a non-Russian speaker, I didn't know that. I don't see there being a difference between the two uses of _for_ in English.

Comment: 1) It started to rain on Monday and stopped on Sunday. - It rained ***for*** seven days.
2) They started reducing the price on Monday and finished on Sunday. - They reduced the price ***over*** seven days. *(not **for)***

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean by _started reducing the price_? As I said in my original answer, it would be _for_ if the same low price was charged all week, _over_ if it got lower every day - which is, admittedly, less likely than in the 'interest rate' example.

Comment: By 'started reducing the price' I mean that on the first day the price was lower than the day before and so on. On the seventh day the price was the lowest.

Comment: But I said all that in my original answer!

Comment: I'm not arguing with you! Everything I said was not to argue, but to discuss :)